# Swift 2: screen rotation only on full screen video

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, screen-orientation

This is a popular question but I couldn't find any solution that worked on Swift 2.

The app is portrait only. But while watching full screen videos, such as YouTube, the users should be able to rotate to landscape.

On Objective C, this was the easiest solution and I used for a long time:

```
AppDelegate file:

static NSString * const VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS7 = @"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController";
static NSString * const VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS8 = @"AVFullScreenViewController";

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

    if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS7)] ||
[[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS8)]) {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

    } else {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    }

}
```

This allows all orientations while the video is on full screen. Otherwise, Portrait only.

But I'm having a hard time to make this work on Swift. Is it possible to make the screen rotate when full screen videos are player on Swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        var classesToCheckFor = [AnyClass]()

        if let ios7Class = NSClassFromString("MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController") {
            classesToCheckFor.append(ios7Class)
        }

        if let ios8Class = NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController") {
            classesToCheckFor.append(ios8Class)
        }

        for classToCheckFor in classesToCheckFor {
            if (self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.isKindOfClass(classToCheckFor) != nil) {
                return .AllButUpsideDown
            }
        }

        return .Portrait
    }
```

`NSClassFromString` can potentially return `nil`, but `isKindOfClass` requires a non-optional `AnyClass`.  I'm checking to see if each class can be loaded on the platform, adding the classes that are loaded to an array, and then iterating through the array of classes, checking to see if the `presentedViewController` is of either class.  If it is, we return `.AllButUpsideDown`.  If neither class can be loaded, or the `presentedViewController`'s is not of either class, then we return `.Portrait`.

Comment: iOS 8 is not rotating, but works great on iOS 9. Thanks!

Comment: To make sure the app will return to portrait, it's better use "supportedInterfaceOrientations" instead of "supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow". This way when the video is dismissed the orientation will go back to portrait automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that was a byproduct of rushing and using autocomplete...  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

Here the solution for iOS 10:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

if let presentedViewController = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
    let className = String(describing: type(of: presentedViewController))
    if ["MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController", "MPMoviePlayerViewController", "AVFullScreenViewController"].contains(className)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
    }
}

return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.2 version of Natividad Lara Diaz answer :

```
if let presentedViewController = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
    let className = String(presentedViewController.dynamicType)
    if ["MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController", "MPMoviePlayerViewController", "AVFullScreenViewController"].contains(className) {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code based on others answer

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        if let videoClass = NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController"), self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.isKind(of: videoClass) != nil {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        }

    return [.portrait]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this solution works very easily without any efforts for swift 3:

in AppDelegate.swift, add this function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if window == self.window {
        return .portrait
    } else {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    }
}
```